# Error caused when forking

Tags: c++, c, fork, pipe

I have the following code which forks two new processes to take the contents of the stdout of one and saves it to a file. It runs just fine and saves the file,  but after it returns the following line in the calling function (no matter what it is) throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Why?

```
void test(vector<string> inp,int i){
    int fds[2]; // file descriptors
    long count;  // used for reading from stdout
    int fd;     // single file descriptor
    char c;     // used for writing and reading a character at a time
    pid_t pid;  // will hold process ID; used with fork()

    pipe(fds);

    // child process #1.
    fd = open((inp[i+1]).c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        if (fd < 0) {
            return;
        }

        dup2(fds[0], 0);

        // Don't need stdout end of pipe.
        close(fds[1]);

        // Read from stdout...
        while ((count = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0)
            write(fd, &c, 1); // Write to file.

        exit(0);
        // child process #2
    } else if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(fds[1], 1);

        // Don't need stdin end of pipe.
        close(fds[0]);

        // Output contents of the given file to stdout.
        char **arguments = getArguments(inp[i]);
        execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
        perror("execvp failed");
        exit(0);
        // parent process
    } else {
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        close(fds[0]);
        close(fds[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is overcomplicated and does not compile as it is. Try to break it down and find the simplest version that reproduces the error, then post minimal complete code.

Comment: try to manage your processes in much better way. you might be trying to read or write to an invalid descriptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well for me:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void test(/*vector<string> inp,int i*/){
    int fds[2]; // file descriptors
    long count;  // used for reading from stdout
    int fd;     // single file descriptor
    char c;     // used for writing and reading a character at a time
    pid_t pid;  // will hold process ID; used with fork()

    pipe(fds);

    // child process #1.
    fd = open(/*(inp[i+1]).c_str()*/"/tmp/output", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        if (fd < 0) {
            return;
        }

        dup2(fds[0], 0);

        // Don't need stdout end of pipe.
        close(fds[1]);

        // Read from stdout...
        while ((count = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0)
            write(fd, &c, 1); // Write to file.

        _exit(0);
        // child process #2
    } else if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(fds[1], 1);

        // Don't need stdin end of pipe.
        close(fds[0]);

        // Output contents of the given file to stdout.
        char **arguments = new char*[2];/*getArguments(inp[i]);*/
        arguments[0]=(char*)"/bin/bash";
        arguments[1]=0;
        execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
        perror("execvp failed");
        _exit(0);
        // parent process
    } else {
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        close(fds[0]);
        close(fds[1]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    test();
}
```

Try to tell where exactly your error appears or show more of your program, so i can try to replicate your conditions.